# UISliders overlap after transforming

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I'm currently trying to create four vertical sliders in Objective-C. I'm able to rotate them using `CGAffineTransform`, but right now each slider is stacked on top of one another. How do you change the coordinates of the sliders so this doesn't happen?

Below is my code for rotating the sliders:

```
CGAffineTransform trans1 = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1.5);
_grainPitchSlider.transform = trans1;

CGAffineTransform trans2 = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1.5);
_grainOffsetSlider.transform = trans2;

CGAffineTransform trans3 = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1.5);
_grainDensitySlider.transform = trans3;

CGAffineTransform trans4 = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1.5);
_grainDurationSlider.transform = trans4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the "center" of each slider, i.e. `_grainPitchSlider.center = CGPointMake(x, y);`

Comment: That does make sense (thank you for answering, @Keller!) 
However, regardless of what I set the x and y coordinates too, I still get a result like this (uploaded screenshot): http://tinypic.com/r/2qu6gyc/5

Comment: Then they must be moved somewhere else. Do you have autolayout turned on?

Comment: @Cyrille, no I didn't but now it works perfectly, thank you both!